# Help with Report Viewer

Tags: c#, reportviewer

My Items table contains items with each item has a specific date. I want to generate a report that displays items between two different dates. For example, I'd put two timedatepicker controls so the user selects From: 24/9/2009 To: 19/3/2010 and then press a button to generate a report of items between these dates.

I'm using Report Viewer control btw not crystal report.

Edit:

Alright I figured it out using linq query and bind it to datasource like this:

```
var query = from c in MyDatabase01DataSet.Items 
                    where c.ProductDate >= Convert.ToDateTime(x) && c.ProductDate <= Convert.ToDateTime(y) 
                    select c;
        ItemsBindingSource.DataSource = query.ToList();

        reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "[reportTest.Report3.rdlc";
        reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = "Report3.rdlc";
        reportViewer1.ProcessingMode = Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ProcessingMode.Local;
        reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```

Answer (score 1):

- Use date(From/to) in the where clause of your query. Or if you have it in a `DataTable`, use [`.Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.select%28VS.71%29.aspx) to filter specific records. Something like following:

  string strFilter = "dateFromCol > " + DateFrom.Value + " and dateToCol < " + DateTo.Value;
  yourTable.Select(strFilter);
- Bind the .DataSource property with your DataTable.

  reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("yourDataSourceName", yourTable));
- Refresh your ReportViewer

[This article](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/DataSetReports04252007100945AM/DataSetReports.aspx) has simple example that might help you get started.

Comment: I figured it out another way though. But thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

```
var query = from c in MyDatabase01DataSet.Items 
                    where c.ProductDate >= Convert.ToDateTime(x) && c.ProductDate <= Convert.ToDateTime(y) 
                    select c;

        ItemsBindingSource.DataSource = query.ToList();

        reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "[reportTest.Report3.rdlc";
        reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = "Report3.rdlc";
        reportViewer1.ProcessingMode = Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ProcessingMode.Local;
        reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```